# Any word for the study of the origins of notations?

Tags: single-word-requests

Etymology is the study of the origin of words and the way in which their meanings have changed throughout history.

Is there such word to designate the study of the origins of notations? (mathematical, musical, etc. notations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a specific field of study of the origins of all notations. ***History*** deals with it.

There are different types of notations from different areas like mathematics, physics, chemistry, music etc. History of a specific field covers the investigation of the origin of the notations of that field.

For example:

> The area of study known as the history of mathematics is primarily an investigation into the origin of discoveries in mathematics and, the focus here, the investigation into the mathematical methods and notation of the past.
>
> <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematical_notation</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try ***iconology***.  "[The branch of art history that deals with the description, analysis, and interpretation of icons or iconic representations.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iconology)"

Notations are visual icons that represent sounds or formulas in their respective domains, so I think it should be appropriate.